# SOAP webservice client code generation using Apache Axis2 XMLBeans in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, apache-axis, webservice-client, xmlbeans, invocationtargetexception

I am tring to generate the Webservice client code using Apache Axis2(1.6.2) in eclipse.

I am using Axis2 eclipse plugin to generate client code.
I am able to generate client code using ADB databinding method however When I try to use XMLBean databinding method I get below exception:

```
Exception occurred during code generation for WSDL  : org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.consumption.core.command.Axis2ClientCodegenCommand.execute(Axis2ClientCodegenCommand.java:222)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:419)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:359)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:254)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:294)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1029)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:264)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:91)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.performFinish(WizardPageManager.java:262)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.DynamicWizard.performFinish(DynamicWizard.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4128)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1457)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1480)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1270)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3974)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3613)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.popup.DynamicPopupWizard.run(DynamicPopupWizard.java:130)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4128)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1457)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1480)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1270)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3974)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3613)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:293)
... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.XMLBeansExtension.engage(XMLBeansExtension.java:126)
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:246)
... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.XMLBeansExtension.engage(XMLBeansExtension.java:115)
... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Imported schema has a target namespace "null" that does not match the specified ""
at org.apache.axis2.xmlbeans.CodeGenerationUtility.processSchemas(CodeGenerationUtility.java:325)
... 69 more
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Imported schema has a target namespace "null" that does not match the specified ""
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemCompiler.compile(SchemaTypeSystemCompiler.java:225)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.compileXmlBeans(XmlBeans.java:667)
at org.apache.axis2.xmlbeans.CodeGenerationUtility.processSchemas(CodeGenerationUtility.java:189)
... 69 more
```

Note: I get the same error when I am trying to generate code using command line argument. and Client code works perfectly with the ADB data binding.

I am able to generate the cline code with Axis1 using XMLBean databinding method however I want to use Axis2.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with WSDL file, After modifying the Targetnamespace of WSDL and XSD file, all working fine.
I think XMLBean require WSDL to be defined in specific way. Thanks!!